# Unique username and unique email on sign up amplify Cognito React

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am working on react project.
The problem I am getting is,
I can either create unique username or unique email .
If I choose username to be unique **I can sign up many account with same email** but I don't won't that, If I choose email to be **unique username is auto generated by aws** which is also not what I want.
Is there possible way where I can have unique user chosen username and unique email.
If possible I want this to be happen programmatically during CloudFormation *file amplify/backend/auth/{projectname}/template.yaml*

```
# BEGIN USER POOL RESOURCES
  UserPool:
  # Created upon user selection
  # Depends on SNS Role for Arn if MFA is enabled
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !If [ShouldNotCreateEnvResources, !Ref userPoolName, !Join ['',[!Ref userPoolName, '-', !Ref env]]]
      
      
      UsernameConfiguration:
        CaseSensitive: false
      
      Schema:
        
        -
          Name: email
          Required: true
          Mutable: true
        
      
      
      
      AutoVerifiedAttributes: !Ref autoVerifiedAttributes
      
      
      EmailVerificationMessage: !Ref emailVerificationMessage
      EmailVerificationSubject: !Ref emailVerificationSubject
      
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: !Ref passwordPolicyMinLength
          RequireLowercase: false
          RequireNumbers: false
          RequireSymbols: false
          RequireUppercase: false
      
      MfaConfiguration: !Ref mfaConfiguration
      SmsVerificationMessage: !Ref smsVerificationMessage
      SmsAuthenticationMessage: !Ref smsAuthenticationMessage
      SmsConfiguration:
        SnsCallerArn: !GetAtt SNSRole.Arn
        ExternalId: dogeco219bfa38_role_external_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this with `amplify`, but I think you will need to create a pre-signup lambda to enforce this. See:

[AWS Cognito: How can I prevent multiple registrations with the same email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478235/aws-cognito-how-can-i-prevent-multiple-registrations-with-the-same-email-addres)

Personally, I would just use email as the login username:

```
UsernameAttributes:
        - email
```

but if you're not able to do so as you require a user created username, then you can add a lambda in Amplify and link it to Cognito in the cloudformation template.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-lambdaconfig.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-lambdaconfig-presignup