# Cognito federated login - Map userpool email and username both to federated identity email

Tags: amazon-cognito, federated-identity, aws-userpools

I am having a Cognito userpool where currently only the Cognito login is supported and no social identity provider is supported. Users sign-up with their email and password where the email is also used as the username.

Now we are adding support for Amazon login (Login With Amazon) along with Cognito login in the userpool and to make it work with the existing users in the pool, we want to set up the attribute mapping such that the LoginWithAmazon email is mapped to userpool email as well as username. But currently, cognito forces userpool username to be mapped to LoginWithAmazon user_id only.

Comment: But, why do you want to do that?

Comment: There is already a whole pool of users where the email Id is used as the username (basically username and email have same value). Now if we allow LWA, it is possible someone can create 2 accounts using these 2 login methods having same email Id. If email Is is used as username then that will be mitigated because cognito will allow unique usernames only

Comment: You need a pre-signup lambda to prevent duplicate emails. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66489649/1273882